# Determine $x$ if $x = 4 \mod 17$ and $x = 3 \mod 11$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, systems-of-equations, congruences

Given $x =4\mod 17$ and $x = 3\mod 11$, determine $x$.

I know that $\gcd(17,11)= 1$. I was hoping to use this to determine $x$.

Comment: $157 {}{}{}{}{}{}$, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem

Comment: By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, there are infinitely many solutions congruent mod $187$.

Comment: I'm confused, 4 mod 17 = 4 but 3 mod 11 = 3. x can't equal 3 and 4.

Comment: @user7348 It's not about equality, its about modular arithmetic. $x \equiv y(\textrm{mod }n)$ means that $n$ divides $x-y$. $17$ divides $157-4$ and $11$ divides $157-3$ so it is such a number. And, of course, it is equal to neither $3$ nor $4$. (To avoid confusion, $\equiv$ is better to use than $=$ here, but it's generally understand what the symbol means by context.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the second congruence,

$x = 11k + 3, k \in \mathbb{Z}$

Substitute into first congruence,

$11k + 3 = 4 \pmod{17}$

$11k = 1 \pmod{17}$

$k \equiv 11^{-1}\pmod{17}$

Solving for the inverse using the Extended Euclidean Algorithm, we get:

$k \equiv 14 \pmod{17}$

or $k = 17m + 14, m \in \mathbb{Z}$

Hence $x = 11(17m + 14) + 3 = 187m + 157$

giving the solution $x \equiv 157 \pmod{187}$.

Comment: How did you calculate that $11^{-1} (mod 17) = 14 (mod 17)$

Comment: @jd123 You can use any implementation of the Extended Euclidean Algorithm. I find the "magic box" method most convenient and easy to apply by hand. You can find it here: http://www.wikipedia.or.ke/index.php/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm (search for the text string "magic box"). Funnily enough, it seems to be absent from the main wiki page on the topic.

Comment: I figured it out! $2x17 - 3x11 = 1$ thus $11^{-1} = -3 (mod) 17 = 14 (mod 17)$. Thank You for your help

Comment: @jd123 Brilliant, exactly! And the magic box algorithm gives you an easy and consistent way to solve for the modular inverse wherever it exists. :)

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

The two congruences are equivalent to $$x=4+17n=3+11m$$ We solve the equation $$11m-17n=1$$ of which a particular solution is $(m,n)=(31,20)$ hence all the solutions are given by $$\begin{cases}m=31+17t\\n=20+11t\end{cases}$$

Thus all the solutions $x$ are given by$$x=4+17(20+11t)=344+187t=\color{red}{157+187t}$$ where $t$ is an arbitrary integer the minimun positive being $157$ corresponding to $t=0$.